# Deploying Grafana using ECS/Fargate issues

Tags: grafana, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm attempting to deploy the image grafana/grafana to aws using ECS fargate. The default port for the grafana container is 3000. I created an ALB listening on port 80 with a target group having port 3000 and attached it to the ECS cluster. I am not able to register any instances(as fargate is self managed and doesnt present any instances). Even when attempting to hit the public IP of a task, e.g IP:3000 I get service unavailable.

I have also verified that the route tables have access to the internet gateway and the security group associated with the VPC allows inbound requests to port 80 and 3000.

What am I doing wrong?

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cloudformation that will deploy grafana to fargate, configuring a load balancer and target group. It will authenticate using an IAM role so no need to muck around with access keys etc.

https://github.com/mark-vandenbos/grafana-fargate

Answer (score 0):

Probably the task is having issues to start, you should to to the ECS task and there is a tab to check the logs of this task. There you will have a more clear description of the issue and will be able to help